# RVM ERRORS - unable to clone RVM repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am trying to install RVM, but I get this error.

```
 Last login: Thu Mar 31 15:41:06 on ttys000
G-Mac-5:~ macbookpro$ bash < <(curl -B http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5335  100  5335    0     0   7948      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14113
bash: line 114: git: command not found
bash: line 115: git: command not found

ERROR: Unable to clone the RVM repository, attempted both git:// and https://
```

Do I need to install GIT first? And whats the diffrents between zsh and bash?

Comment: I installed git and then installed RVM, it workt. =)

Comment: looks like tadman also answered so i guess you should accept his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really should be better diagnostic messages when something about the installation fails. Phusion Passenger is an example of how to do it right, where not only are rigorous tests done prior to the installation attempt, but any problems are explained with cut-and-pasteable examples on how to fix them. They're even customized to the particular OS you're using, differentiating between `apt-get` and `yum` among other things.

If you're missing `git`, you won't get very far with `rvm`.

Comment: The installtion is complete now, but when I run commands like 'rvm update --head' and 'rvm reload'.. it says: '-bash: rvm: command not found
'

Comment: solution: I created .bash_profile and add the following line:

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Comment: Does `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` exist on your system? A lot of the internals of `rvm` changed in the most recent 1.5.x release.